# Yet another regex - how to identify a querystring

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, regex-greedy, urlrewriting.net

I am using urlrewriting.net for my urlrewriting. I need some help on the regex (which I still don't get....).

I would like to match

- `www.mysite.com/restaurant` -> match and return
  "`restaurant`"
- `www.mysite.com/restaurant?page=1` -> match and
  return "`restaurant`"
- `www.mysite.com/restaurant?[SOME_RANDOM_QUERYSTRING]` -> match 
  and return "`restaurant`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant` -> match and return "`seattle`" and
  "`restaurant`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant?page=1` -> match and
  return "`seattle`" and "`restaurant`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant?[SOME_RANDOM_QUERYSTRING]` -> match 
  and return "`seattle`" and "`restaurant`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant-michelangelo` -> don't catch
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant/sushi` -> match and return "`seattle`"
  and "`restaurant`" and "`sushi`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant/sushi?page=1` -> match and return
  "`seattle`" and "`restaurant`" and "`sushi`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant/sushi?[SOME_RANDOM_QUERYSTRING]` ->
  match and return "`seattle`" and "`restaurant`" and "`sushi`"
- `www.mysite.com/seattle/restaurant-michelangelo` -> don't catch

The point being I need the directory-parts of the url and not the querystring-parts. The thing is that I can see from my web analytics tool, that people search by two words. They both search for the city (seattle) + category (restaurant) eg. "seattle restaurant" and also for the city (seattle) + the name of the restaurant (restaurant-michelangelo) eg. "seattle restaurant-michelangelo". From a structural point of view, this is of course a mess, since this is not a hierarchy. In the ideal world the hierarchy would be city -> category -> restaurant. but I would still like to accommodate this search behavior in my url-structure. At the same time I also have a page listing all restaurants in the country.

I would like help on how to create the regexes as well as the most efficient way of creating them since I guess they could become quite expensive.

thanks

Thomas

Comment: And how do you differentiate between a category and a name? All names have dashes in them or what?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
/\/[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}(?:\/|$|\?)/
```

Matches / Alphanumerics 1-infininity then slash, End of Line, or Question mark

Comment: Hmm... I can't get it to work. I don't have that many categories, so maybe I should just do something like ^~/(.*)/restaurant, ^~/(.*)/café etc. I then need to remove any querystring (if they are present). So how would a regex look which would remove the querystring (if it is present) regardless of the number of parameters in the querystring? Thanks